# Why i am getting ConcurrentModificationException after running my app for a while?

Tags: android, runtime-error, runnable, achartengine, concurrentmodification

i am developing an application and i am using achartengine to draw a chart which shows data which are random numbers now to test. It works as expected but after a few seconds running it crash and it seams to crash when it tries to put the run() Thread to sleep. It is the LogCat:

```
04-22 18:22:02.253: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:02.262: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(5.1999974),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:02.271: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:02.271: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:02.781: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:02.781: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(5.2999973),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:02.802: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:02.802: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:03.182: D/dalvikvm(1902): GC_CONCURRENT freed 445K, 6% free 9330K/9863K, paused 42ms+33ms
04-22 18:22:03.522: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:03.522: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(5.399997),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:03.522: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:03.522: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:04.052: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:04.052: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(5.499997),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:04.084: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:04.084: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:04.607: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:04.612: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(5.599997),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:04.622: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:04.632: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:05.131: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:05.131: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(5.699997),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:05.163: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:05.163: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:05.687: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:05.687: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(5.799997),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:05.691: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:05.691: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:06.302: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:06.302: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(5.8999968),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:06.351: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:06.351: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:06.962: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:06.962: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(5.9999967),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:06.962: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:06.991: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:07.491: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:07.491: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(6.0999966),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:07.521: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:07.521: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:07.933: D/dalvikvm(1902): GC_CONCURRENT freed 436K, 6% free 9334K/9863K, paused 12ms+62ms
04-22 18:22:08.061: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:08.061: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(6.1999965),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:08.061: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:08.061: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:08.133: D/AndroidRuntime(1902): Shutting down VM
04-22 18:22:08.133: W/dalvikvm(1902): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x409c01f8)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902): java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at java.util.TreeMap$MapIterator.stepForward(TreeMap.java:883)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at java.util.TreeMap$BoundedMap$BoundedIterator.stepForward(TreeMap.java:1484)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at java.util.TreeMap$BoundedMap$BoundedEntrySet$1.next(TreeMap.java:1512)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at java.util.TreeMap$BoundedMap$BoundedEntrySet$1.next(TreeMap.java:1510)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.draw(XYChart.java:250)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onDraw(GraphicalView.java:166)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10978)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2887)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:2885)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:2489)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.View.draw(View.java:10981)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:450)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2126)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2026)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1634)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
04-22 18:22:08.481: E/AndroidRuntime(1902):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-22 18:22:08.561: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:08.561: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(6.2999964),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:08.581: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:08.581: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:09.112: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:09.112: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(6.3999963),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:09.131: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:09.131: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:09.495: I/dalvikvm(1902): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-22 18:22:09.671: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:09.681: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(6.499996),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:09.691: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:09.701: I/dalvikvm(1902): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-22 18:22:09.731: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:10.231: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:10.231: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(6.599996),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:10.251: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:10.251: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:10.572: I/dalvikvm(1902): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-22 18:22:11.101: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:11.101: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(6.699996),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:11.101: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:11.101: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:11.155: I/dalvikvm(1902): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-22 18:22:11.615: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:11.615: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(6.799996),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:11.641: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:11.641: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:12.182: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:12.182: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(6.899996),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:12.213: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:12.213: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:12.381: I/dalvikvm(1902): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-22 18:22:12.581: I/dalvikvm(1902): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-22 18:22:12.762: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:12.762: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(6.9999957),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:12.821: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:12.821: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:13.134: I/dalvikvm(1902): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-22 18:22:13.351: I/dalvikvm(1902): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-22 18:22:13.361: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:13.361: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(7.0999956),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:13.361: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:13.361: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:13.491: I/dalvikvm(1902): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-22 18:22:13.551: I/dalvikvm(1902): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-22 18:22:13.873: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:13.873: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(7.1999955),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:13.873: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:13.873: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:14.001: I/dalvikvm(1902): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-22 18:22:14.073: I/dalvikvm(1902): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-22 18:22:14.422: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:14.422: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(7.2999954),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:14.422: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:14.422: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:14.541: I/dalvikvm(1902): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-22 18:22:14.621: I/dalvikvm(1902): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-22 18:22:14.921: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:14.933: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(7.3999953),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:14.953: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:14.953: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:15.151: I/dalvikvm(1902): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-22 18:22:15.401: I/dalvikvm(1902): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-22 18:22:15.461: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:15.461: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(7.499995),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:15.461: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:15.474: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:15.601: I/dalvikvm(1902): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-22 18:22:15.661: I/dalvikvm(1902): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-22 18:22:16.028: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:16.028: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(7.599995),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:16.031: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:16.031: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:16.171: I/dalvikvm(1902): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-22 18:22:16.241: I/dalvikvm(1902): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-22 18:22:16.591: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:16.591: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(7.699995),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:16.621: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:16.621: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:16.731: I/dalvikvm(1902): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-22 18:22:16.791: I/dalvikvm(1902): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-22 18:22:17.145: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:17.145: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(7.799995),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:17.145: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:17.145: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:17.271: I/dalvikvm(1902): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-22 18:22:17.331: I/dalvikvm(1902): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-22 18:22:17.684: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:17.684: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(7.899995),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:17.704: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:17.711: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:17.831: I/dalvikvm(1902): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-22 18:22:17.902: I/dalvikvm(1902): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-22 18:22:18.221: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:18.231: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(7.9999948),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:18.243: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:18.243: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:18.364: I/dalvikvm(1902): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-22 18:22:18.442: I/dalvikvm(1902): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-22 18:22:18.795: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:18.795: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(8.099995),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:18.802: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:18.815: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:18.932: I/dalvikvm(1902): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-22 18:22:18.991: I/dalvikvm(1902): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-22 18:22:19.371: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:19.371: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(8.199995),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:19.392: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:19.392: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:19.441: I/dalvikvm(1902): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-22 18:22:19.522: I/dalvikvm(1902): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-22 18:22:19.952: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:19.952: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(8.299995),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:19.952: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:19.952: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:20.002: I/dalvikvm(1902): threadid=3: reacting to signal 3
04-22 18:22:20.074: I/dalvikvm(1902): Wrote stack traces to '/data/anr/traces.txt'
04-22 18:22:20.513: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:20.513: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(8.399996),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:20.534: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:20.534: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:21.066: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:21.092: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(8.499996),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:21.102: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:21.112: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:21.623: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:21.623: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(8.599997),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:21.623: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:21.623: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:22.152: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:22.161: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(8.699997),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:22.173: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:22.182: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:22.711: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:22.761: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(8.799997),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:22.761: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:22.761: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:23.295: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:23.295: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(8.899998),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:23.314: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:23.314: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:23.884: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:23.884: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(8.999998),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:23.884: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:23.884: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:24.383: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:24.391: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(9.099998),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:24.391: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:24.391: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:24.901: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:24.901: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(9.199999),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:24.911: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:24.911: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:25.466: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:25.491: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(9.299999),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:25.511: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:25.511: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:26.045: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:26.045: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(9.4),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:26.071: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:26.071: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:26.592: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:26.601: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(9.5),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:26.613: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:26.613: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:27.133: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:27.133: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(9.6),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:27.141: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:27.161: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:27.682: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:27.682: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(9.700001),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:27.691: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:27.691: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:28.217: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:28.217: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(9.800001),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:28.221: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:28.231: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:28.779: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:28.781: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(9.900002),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:28.791: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:28.801: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:29.320: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:29.321: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(10.000002),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:29.321: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:29.331: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:29.882: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:29.882: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(10.100002),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:29.882: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:29.882: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:30.410: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:30.411: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(10.200003),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:30.411: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:30.411: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:30.931: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:30.931: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(10.300003),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:30.931: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:30.931: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:31.464: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:31.464: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(10.400003),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:31.464: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:31.464: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:32.020: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:32.021: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(10.500004),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:32.021: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:32.021: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:32.570: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:32.570: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(10.600004),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:32.570: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:32.570: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:33.094: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:33.094: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(10.700005),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:33.094: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:33.094: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:33.636: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:33.636: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(10.800005),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:33.636: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:33.661: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:34.192: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:34.192: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(10.900005),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:34.192: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:34.192: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:34.743: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:34.743: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(11.000006),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:34.743: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:34.743: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:35.271: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:35.271: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(11.100006),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:35.271: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:35.271: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
04-22 18:22:35.803: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView
04-22 18:22:35.803: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(11.2000065),factor[n]
04-22 18:22:35.811: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()
04-22 18:22:35.811: I/(1902): run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()
```

As far i can see i think the problem is on ConcurrentModificationException, i have investigated about it but i cant understand for sure :/.

http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/ConcurrentModificationException.html
http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Collection.html

It is a piece of my Java code where the chart is being redrawed:

```
    //onResume() se llama al resumir la Activity y tambien al crearse la Activity
    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(2);     //seleccion el item 0 (LC)
        //Creo el Thread y lo inicio
        Running = true;
        myThread = new Thread(this);
        myThread.start();
    }

    //onPause() se llama cuando se pausa la Activity y tambien antes de su destruccion
    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        //destruyo el Thread
        Running = false;
        try {
            myThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        myThread = null;    //pongo el Thread como null para no provocar errores
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {

        while(Running){

            int[] factor = {0, 2, 4, 6}; 

            if(DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "run() -> LogicAnalizerView");

            data = USBMulti.getLogicAnalizerData();
            for(int n = 0; n < 4; ++n){
                if(bitTest(data,n)) factor[n] += 1;
            }

            if(DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "run() -> LogicAnalizerView - input.add(" + time + "),factor[n]");
            input1.add(time,factor[0]);
            input2.add(time,factor[1]);
            input3.add(time,factor[2]);
            input4.add(time,factor[3]);

            if(DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()");
            mView.repaint();    // Redibujo el grafico
            time += 0.1;

            if(DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "run() -> LogicAnalizerView - Thread.sleep()");

            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }

    }
```

Thanks you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok i have found the solution. The problem is i am updating the UI in a Thread that is not an UI Thread so i have to use a Handler as below and put the code that modifies the UI in the Handler, I call the Handler from my run() method:

```
uiCallback.sendEmptyMessage(0);
```

The Handler is called uiCallback and i define the Handler on this way:

```
private Handler uiCallback = new Handler () {
    public void handleMessage (Message msg) {
        if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "run() -> Handler");
        int[] factor = {0, 2, 4, 6};

        data = USBMulti.getLogicAnalizerData();
        for(int n = 0; n < 4; ++n) {
            if(bitTest(data,n)) factor[n] += 1;
        }

        input1.add(time,factor[0]);
        input2.add(time,factor[1]);
        input3.add(time,factor[2]);
        input4.add(time,factor[3]);

        if (DEBUG) Log.i(TAG, "run() -> LogicAnalizerView - mView.repaint()");
        if (mView != null) {
            mView.repaint(); // Redibujo el grafico
        }
        time += 0.1;
    }
};
```

So i repaint the chart on the UI Thread and it works perfectly :).

Thanks you :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks to me like you're calling `.add` on your dataset, at the same time that the *achartengine* is iterating through the same dataset.

I'm not 100% sure how repaint works, but if it launches in another thread you may need some way to synchronize so that it's not reading your dataset at the same time you're modifying it.

Don't know exactly how to do that, but I hope this points you in the right direction.

Comment: Yeah that was what i tought but i cannot get any information about how repaint works and i dont know how can i sinchronize them :/

Comment: @Andres what kind of view is 'mView'?

Comment: mView is a GraphicalView type and i set it whit setContentView(mView);